# Segmentation faults and structure

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I want this program to read an input file then save individual words and their frequencies to a structure then print the structure's contents to an output file. I am getting segmentation faults but i don't know why. Also I am not sure if I have written the program correctly. Appreciate the help.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

struct string_count
{
char *str;
int *str_freq;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int i=0, j, temp;
char *str_temp, *temp2;
struct string_count *word ;
FILE *fp1, *fp2;

fp1 = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if( fp1 == NULL )
{
     printf("Input file can't be opened");
     exit(1);
}    
fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "w");
if (fp2 == NULL)
{ 
    printf("Error: Output file can't be created");
    exit (1);
}
fgets(str_temp, 50000000, fp1);
str_temp = (char*)malloc(5000000*sizeof(char));
fclose(fp1);
word->str = (char*)malloc(strlen(str_temp)*sizeof(char));
word->str_freq = (int*)malloc(strlen(str_temp)*sizeof(int));
word->str[0] = (char*)strtok(str_temp, " ,;(){}""'");
word->str_freq[0] = 0;
word->str_freq[0]++;
while(getc(fp2) != EOF)
{
    i++;
    word->str[i] = (char*)strtok(NULL, " ,;(){}""'");
    for (j=0, word->str[i]=0;j < i;j++)
    {
        if( word->str[i] = word->str[j]) word->str_freq[i]++;
    }
}
for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
{
    if (word->str_freq[j] > word->str_freq[j - 1])
    {
          temp = word->str_freq[j];
          word->str_freq[j] = word->str_freq[j - 1];
          word->str_freq[j - 1] = temp;
          str_temp = word->str[j];
          word->str[j] = word->str[j - 1];
          word->str[j - 1] = str_temp;
    }   
}
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    fprintf(fp2, "%s    %d\n", word->str[j], word->str_freq[j]);             
}
fclose(fp2);
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do to here? word->str[0] = (char*)strtok(str_temp, " ,;(){}""'");

Comment: try to debug with gdb

Comment: No need for a debugger: `word->str =` word is uninitialised at this point.

Comment: one more problem is with str_temp. you are doing fgets first then malloc,do first malloc and then fgets

Comment: You are using str_temp before allocating it.  Switch the fgets and malloc statements.  Also stdio.h and any system headers should be in <>.  Use == for comparison: you're using =.  Also your sort won't work.

Answer (score 0):

you have done so many mistake first here

`str_temp = (char*)malloc(5000000*sizeof(char));`

use it before fgets line before and here also

`word->str = (char*)malloc(strlen(str_temp)*sizeof(char));`

here you have not allocated memory to word struct pointer and further giving memory to other its member . do correct these